# React JS how to pass props from a component to another component

Tags: reactjs

I have this react code where I don't know how to do it better.

I will start like this.

I have 3 `react` components as of now, namely `Main`, `Form`, `NextButton`

So my `Main` component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form"; 
import NextButton from "./NextButton";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form />
        <NextButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

`Form` contains some Text Fields, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Age`

And `NextButton` component contains a `react-bootstrap` `Button` just to navigate to the next page with `react-router-dom`, nothing fancy.

My problem is:

I want to pass the value of `First Name` to the page I render when clicking `NextButton` through `props`

So the `NextButton` would look something like this:

```
<NextButton firstname={value-i-get-from-Form-component}/>
```

I know `react` only allows one-direction data passing, but I want to make this work. Means If my current setup in the `Main` component is not right, How should I change it?

Comment: You need some sort of change handler passed to Form `onChange` or something, and then you need to store that value in some sort of state (redux, component state, etc)

Comment: if you are working with functional component then use useContext() hook or go with Context for class component

Comment: @bluetoft can you provide a solution with `redux` I am new to `react`

Answer (score 1):

With a functional component you can keep state in the parent and pass the hook to the child which can then update the parent. You can also pass a handler to the child and use it to update the parent.

With a functional component it could look like this:

```
function Main(props) {
   
   const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState('');

   return (
     <div>
       <Form setFirstName={setFirstName} firstName={firstName} />
       <NextButton firstName={firstName} />
     </div>
   );
}
```

Inside Form you can update the state like this

```
function Form({ firstName, setFirstName }) {

   const handleChange = (event) => {
      setFirstName(event.target.value)
   }
   
   return (
     <div>
       <TextField onChange={handleChange} value={firstName} />
     </div>
   );
}
```

This will render that new state in the parent which will pass it to NextButton.

Comment: Can you provide the content I should write in the `Form` component? now that the `setFirstName` is given?

Comment: I edited the answer to include this, assuming you are using a text field to collect name data. You also need to pass firstName into Form to set the value of the text field

Comment: Is it possible to convert the `Form` component to a class component instead of a `functional` component?

Comment: Yes form can be a class.

Comment: You will access the props as ```props.firstName``` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from `Form` to `Main` by calling function prop when your `First Name` input change.

**Main component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form"; 
import NextButton from "./NextButton";

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      formValue: {}
    }
  }

  handleChange(formValue) {
    this.setState(formValue)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.formValue} />
        <NextButton firstName={this.state.formValue.firstName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**Form component can be like:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)

    this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this)
    this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this)
    this.handleAgeChange = this.handleAgeChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleFirstNameChange(event) {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        ...this.props.value,  // keep the other values like lastName, age
        firstName: event.target.value, 
      })
    }
  }

  handleLastNameChange(event) {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        ...this.props.value,  // keep the other values like firstName, age
        lastName: event.target.value, 
      })
    }
  }

  handleAgeChange(event) {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        ...this.props.value,  // keep the other values like firstName, lastName
        age: event.target.value, 
      })
    }
  }


  render() {
    let { firstName, lastName, age } = this.props.value
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} />
        <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} />
        <input type="text" value={age} onChange={this.handleAgeChange} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

If your component hierarchy getting complicated you can use `Redux`.

Comment: So now with these changes, how should the new `Form` component look like?

Comment: I editted the answer. If you research the concepts of **controlled component** and **uncontrolled component** in React, you can better understand what I'm doing.

Comment: I will check this out and let you know :) Thank you

Comment: I tried this and when I type in the fields, it doesn't type anything.

Comment: And I tried replacing my code with yours, now I can type but the value `firstName` given to `NextButton` is not getting any value

Answer (score 0):

If this were me i would get familiar with using react functional components and hooks since they are way easier to comprehend and understand than redux.
They are very powerful and when you write your own hooks you can share logic in a really easy way across components.

[React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```js
function Main() {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(undefined);
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onChange={setTitle} />
      <NextButton title={title} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Form({ onChange }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const change = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        onChange(value);
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <input onChange={change} type="text" value={value} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function NextButton({ title = "Title" }) {
  return <button>{title}</button>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I would love too but the problem is can I implement everything I do in a `class` component using the `functional` component? (yes I know, syntaxes and logics can be changed, but can we get the same output?)

Comment: absolutely in a much cleaner manor.  all the lifecycle events can be handled using useEffect hooks, setState hooks, etc.  Examples of using class components converted to functional components typically can be written in about a quarter the amount of code.